# Why does C++ not have a "pure" keyword for virtual functions?

Tags: c++, syntax, keywords, virtual-functions

I have always wondered why we code

```
virtual void MyFunction() = 0;
```

and not

```
pure virtual void MyFunction();
```

Is there a reference for the basis of this decision?

Comment: No opinions? Ok then. Because that's how the C++ language is defined.

Comment: Note that a "pure" function often means something unrelated.

Answer (score 73, accepted):

From [The Design and Evolution of C++](http://www.stroustrup.com/dne.html) - Bjarne Stroustrup - Addison-Wesley (ISBN 0-201-54330-3) - chapter 13.2.3:

> The curious `= 0` syntax was chosen over the obvious alternative of introducing a new keyword `pure` or `abstract` because at the time I saw no chance of getting a new keyword accepted. Had I suggested `pure`, Release 2.0 would have shipped without abstract classes. Given a choice between a nicer syntax and abstract classes, I chose abstract classes. Rather than risking delay and incurring the certain fights over `pure`, I used the tradition C and C++ convention of using 0 to represent *not there*.

Anyway looking at the C++ standard (§ 9.2 - Class members) `= 0` is called *pure-specifier*.

Comment: that's cool. Reminds me of why PHP has so many different ugly function names: because the first interpreter used strlen as hash function and distribution should be good (http://www.i-programmer.info/news/98-languages/6758-the-reason-for-the-weird-php-function-names.html)

Comment: The introduction of context-sensitive keywords in C++11 has reduces the damage that adding keywords causes.  It should be possible to make `pure` a contextual keyword you put at the end of a function definition, so `virtual void MyFunction() pure` instead of `= 0`, to go along with `final` and `override`.

Comment: As an aside, nearly everywhere a "pure function" is understood to be a function whose output only depends on its input, and which has no side-effects.

Comment: Pretty much any question of "why does C++ do X?" can be answered by that book.  It should be required reading for any serious C++ programmer.

Comment: Where are these called pure, anyway? Both C# and Java use "abstract" as the keyword here.

Comment: @Aitch, yup. It substituted the (solved) problem of how to hash strings with the (very hard) problems of naming things.

Comment: @Random832 it's "pure virtual" (as in "100% virtual and 0% anything else"), not just "pure".

Comment: @immibis Interestingly the standard still uses the term "abstract class" to refer to a class with at least one pure virtual member function; it uses BOTH terms. Also, are you the "immibis" in "immibis's microblocks"?

Comment: @chbaker0 Classes can't be virtual, so it wouldn't make sense to call them pure virtual classes.

Comment: @chbaker0 Also yes.